# Como ordenar array formado por objetos usando .sort()

Tags: javascript, object

Tengo un fichero que contiene el objeto que quiero manipular. Creo dos por ejemplo. Pero cuando en la funcion de mostrarArrayOrdenado() le aplico el sort() para ordenarlo, al tratarse de objetos y no de literales. no me ordena. Mi idea es que se ordenen por el parametro nombre de cada objeto que compone el array. ¿Es posible?

```js
function Sandskill(nom, edad, especialidad, comp) {
  this.nombre = nom;
  this.edad = edad;
  if (especialidad == 1 || especialidad == 2 || especialidad == 3) {
    if (especialidad == 1)
      this.especialidad = "sistemas";
    if (especialidad == 2)
      this.especialidad = "web";
    if (especialidad == 3)
      this.especialidad = "multiplataforma";
  } else {
    this.especialidad = null;
  }
  this.comp = comp;

  //GETTER
  this.getNom = function() {
    return this.nombre;
  }
  this.getEdad = function() {
    return this.edad;
  }
  this.getEspecialidad = function() {
    return this.especialidad;
  }
  this.getComp = function() {
    return this.comp;
  }
}

var s1 = new Sandskill("Pepe", "22", "1");
var s2 = new Sandskill("Juan", "22", "2", s1);

function mostrarArrayOrdenado() {
  sandskillArray.sort();
  for (i = 0; i < sandskillArray.length; i++) {
    alert(sandskillArray[i].getNom() + " * " + sandskillArray[i].getEdad() + " * " + sandskillArray[i].getEspecialidad() + " * ")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El método sort(), como puedes ver en la web de [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort#Descripci%C3%B3n), puede recibir como parámetro una función de comparadora que tiene la siguiente forma:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a es menor que b según criterio de ordenamiento) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a es mayor que b según criterio de ordenamiento) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a debe ser igual b
  return 0;
}
```

En tu caso, podría ser algo así como:

```
sandskillArray.sort(function (o1,o2) {
  if (o1.nombre > o2.nombre) { //comparación lexicogŕafica
    return 1;
  } else if (o1.nombre < o2.nombre) {
    return -1;
  } 
  return 0;
});
```